# "Cut the Rope" game and used space

Tags: ios, games, storage

Just recently noticed that "Cut the Rope" free versions on my iPad Mini with latest iOS is taking up to 500MB of space. Is it really necessary for them to take up so much space? Maybe someone know to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The used space will likely be cached images, audio and video - there's not a lot you can do to clear the space with the exception of uninstalling it! Don't trust apps that claim they can save you space - they generally end up breaking things!

Comment: Turns out that free HD versions of Cut the Rope really takes 400-500MB each. Haven't noticed that before installation.